# How to pipe grep into a program that uses a directory with only read permissions

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find, pipe

I have a remote directory that I do not have any permissions to other than to read files.

Typically I run a custom server-wide script, dostuff, as such:

```
dostuff /path/to/images/*img
```

However, this directory accidentally has two distinct sets of files (same number of files each) with very similar names:

```
13-08_1_0XXX.img
13-08_1_0XXX_16YYYY.img
```

where Xs increments from 1-900 together, and Ys have somewhat arbitrary numbers.

For example, I can regex select filenames for the first set with:

```
find . | grep -E -w -o ".{12}.img"
```

So I tried

```
find /path/to/images/ | grep -E -w -o ".{12}.img" | dostuff
```

but that does not work. As I can't move the files or copy them elsewhere, I think the only solution is to figure out how to pipe them into the script as two individual sets of images. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What does anything in your question have to do with moving files or the directory only having read permission? Your regexp `".{12}.img"` would match both sets of files btw - you'd have to anchor it `'^.{12}\.img$'` for a different result.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton. I was trying to allude to the fact that if I had file permissions this would be trivial, trying to keep people from saying "just pipe this regexp into mv" sort of thing. Also, you're right that it matches both but I was using the -w flag, in an attempt to only keep those that match the whole 'word'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `GNU findutils`, following should work:

```
$ find /path/to/imagedir -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex '.*/13-08_1_0([1-9][0-9][0-8]|900)(.img|_16[0-9]+{4}.img)' -exec dosomestuff {} \;
```

`-regextype posix-extended -regex` option in `find` gives `grep -E` type functionality.

`{}` is the matched pattern found.

`-exec dosomestuff {}` would _do_some_stuff_ to the matched `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `find...|grep...` command in backquotes, and make that the argument to dostuff. Better is piping to `find ... | grep ... | xargs dostuff`. `xargs` will invoke dostuff with the (stdin stream of) filenames as an argument list. If the list of files would exceed max bash command line length (32KB), xargs breaks it into multiple invocations of dostuff.

Comment: So I tried: `find /path/to/images/ | grep -E -w -o ".{12}.img" | xargs doit` and 'doit find /path/to/images/ | grep -E -w -o ".{12}.img"` (surrounded in backquotes which I can't figure out how to display that as code and escape in SO's markdown) and unfortunately neither worked. Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: Don't do `doit $(find...)` as it'll break given spaces in file names and/or large numbers of files and/or globbing chars, etc., do `find ... | xargs doit` instead. Saying "neither worked" gives us absolutely no information that we could use to help you debug the failure. Tell us in what way it failed - wrong output, no output, error message, core dump etc. Saying "nothing worked" is like taking your car to the mechanic and just saying "it doesn't work" then walking away expecting her to fix it from just that.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point. I should've included them. 

Both methods suggested by Mischa correctly start the script but spit out: `ls: cannot access 13-08_1_0794.img: No such file or directory` even though it's definitely there.

Comment: Wait...what? `find /path  ` will emit pathnames like `/path/.../13-08_1_0794.img`  so doit must be doing something unexpected. Perhaps we could see how it gets to the `ls` ?